# XML RuntimeError: Illegal character '&' in raw string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a request that looks like this;

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = purchase_xml
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.request(request)
result = Hash.from_xml(response.body)
```

However  `result = Hash.from_xml(response.body)` gives me this error:

```
#<RuntimeError: Illegal character '&' in raw string "ybs_autocreate_status=ERROR&ybs_auto
```

Answer (score 3):

Change any instances of `&` to `&amp;` when you are not referring to a character code.